# Swift: comparing 2 object's positions in if statement not working?

Tags: swift

Alright, so I'm trying to do something simple here and I think I've overcomplicated it- I need an if statement saying if this object goes off the screen (into negative y coordinates), have something happen. I can't get it.

I've tried a number of things, including if statements that compare to numbers like this, having it be equal and then trying greater/less than:

```
if block1.position.y == -50 {
            savior.hidden = true
        }
```

I've tried having the object be less than the size of the `self.size.height` :

```
if block1.position.y < self.size.height {
            savior.hidden = true
        }
```

And I've tried placing an object at the point off the screen and having an if statement comparing the 2 object's y positions:

```
if block1.position.y == ptBlock1.position.y {
            savior.hidden = true
        }
```

And nothing's working. Block1, the object I'm working with, is being sent to the specific point in an SKAction, so I know that it's getting there:

```
var moveDownLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.35,-50), duration:5.5)
block1.runAction(moveDownLeft)
```

Why won't the if statement work?

EDIT:

I have tried this, and even when block1 visibly has a y position lower than ptBlock1, nothing happens:

```
if block1.position.y < ptBlock1.position.y {
            savior.hidden = true
        }
else if block1.position.y > ptBlock1.position.y {
savior.hidden = false
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift: if statement using .position not returning results?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882535/swift-if-statement-using-position-not-returning-results)

Comment: Please don't duplicate your own questions, especially not an hour apart. You could have just updated the original question with this detail.

Comment: @Abizern sorry. I felt I had to redo the question. Can you possibly help me with the question here?

Comment: I think Matt's doing a good job here already.

Answer (score 1):

> this object goes off the screen (into negative y coordinates)

You're making a false assumption there. Off the screen is not necessarily negative y coordinates.

The position of an SKNode is not measured with respect to screen; it is measured with respect to its superview, which is the SKScene. And the SKScene is *much* bigger than the screen! You need to convert from those coordinates to screen coordinates if you want to know what's happening relative to the screen.

(Just to give an example, if you make a new SpriteKit project from the template and log on `touchesBegan` to show the tap position, you will discover that a tap in the top left corner is at about `{303,758}`. So in that coordinate system an object is off the screen to the top if its `y` is *greater* than about 760. Contrast that with screen coordinates, where you are off the screen to the top if you are *less* than 0. These are very different coordinate systems!)

Comment: Ok, understandable. But even so, shouldn't I be able to compare the object's position to another object if not to a number?

Comment: But none of the code in your question above compares it to another object. You compare only to numbers, and to the view, which, as I just said, is in a totally different coordinate system.

Comment: Alright, so how would you go about the problem? How can I compare to the screen coordinates?

Comment: I thought comparing one object's position to another's was equivalent to comparing objects

Comment: You were already told in a comment on your duplicate of this question: the chances of two floating point numbers being equal are very slim. Computer math doesn't work that way. You can compare one object's position to another, but not with `==`.

Comment: Sorry. I'm still a little new to this. I've tried comparing the object's positions using greater and less than as well, to no avail.

Comment: What do you mean? They have to be greater than or less than; there is no other possibility.

Comment: I've edited my question with what I've tried. The first object always evaluates to being more than, even when it is visibly less than.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68576/discussion-between-skyguy-and-matt).